# unclear results when using ISODate and JS

Tags: javascript, mongodb

i am facing a strange issue with Data type in javascript when using ISODate format:

```
  this.myTest = new Date('2018-02-28T22:00:00.000Z');
  console.log(this.myTest);
```

and this is what i am getting :

Thu Mar 01 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0200

hwo can it be ?

Thanks

Comment: because it calls the toString() function of date internally

Comment: So it changes the date? The string coming from db, i need the actual date, is there any way to avoid this? The printing is for the example im using it to populate a list and also get the wrong date

Comment: No it doesn't change the date. Console.log uses the tostring